# IOS App Submission Routing App

Tags: ios, submit, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit my app for review in Itunes Connect, but when I try to submit it I get an error:

> To configure this app as an IOS routing app, upload a routing app
>   coverage file on the app's Version page in My Apps on iTunes Connect.
>   To configure your app as an IOS routing app, the app's Info.plist must
>   contain the `MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes` key.

So in my project, in the Capabilities, the Maps is turned off.  I do have the **MapKit.framework** in my project, as I do utilize the map, however I do not ever show routing information nor provide it in my app.  Is the fact that this framework in my project causing this ITunes Connect error, and if so, how do I go about fixing it. And by fixing it, I want it to turn off routing.

My app is not made to provide routing information, nor do I want to set it as an iOS routing app.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using XCode 6.

Comment: It's not a real answer but if you just create a dummy coverage file?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store support, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Comment: No, it's a fine question. Just because there isn't code doesn't mean its off-topic. This is a lot more relevant than many other posts.

Answer (score 12):

I figured it out.  In my info plist there was a document type name of MKDirectionsRequest.  Removing that solved the problem.

Comment: This issue got me TWICE. But this time, your answer helped... and that MKDirections Request was under the Document Types dropdown in the info.plist for me.

Comment: @user3007080 Hi, did you archive and upload to app store again? Thanks!

Comment: @deebs Hi, did you archive and upload to app store again? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

From the apple docs

> (To use the features of the Map Kit framework, you must turn on the
>   Maps capability in your Xcode project.)

above the entire paragraph.(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497)

> Location-based information consists of two pieces: location services
>   and maps. Location services are provided by the Core Location
>   framework, which defines Objective-C interfaces for obtaining
>   information about the user’s location and heading (the direction in
>   which a device is pointing). Maps are provided by the Map Kit
>   framework, which supports both the display and annotation of maps
>   similar to those found in the Maps app. (To use the features of the
>   Map Kit framework, you must turn on the Maps capability in your Xcode
>   project.) Location services and maps are available on both iOS and OS
>   X.

Not sure but maybe you only need to turn on mapkit

Answer (score 4):

In my info.plist I had to delete two entries:

1) the document you referenced above - MKDirectionsRequest

and

2) MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes - MKDirectionsModeCar which is called "Maps routing app supported modes"

Comment: Hi, did you archive and upload to app store again? Thanks!

Comment: I found that I had to perform both of these steps.  Just deleting MKDirectionsRequest cleared up that specific issue but then surfaced another issue

Comment: I found that I had to perform both of these steps.  Just deleting MKDirectionsRequest surfaced another issue saying that "To configure this app as an iOS routing app, the app's Info.plist must contain the MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes key.", so I had to delete MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes as well, then it was all fine.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced this exact issue last week.

I had accidentally turned on Map capabilities and turned it off later. Like your case, this didn't fix the issue.

[image]

I believe what fixed it was **removing** MapKit from here. 
I was trying other things at the time so try this and if this isn't it then I'll see if something else I changed fix this.

Comment: thanks for the help, as my below answer states, in my case their was residue in my info plist of a mapdirectionrequest.