# To configure this app as an iOS routing app, the app's Info.plist must contain the MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes key

Tags: ios, submit

I am trying to submit an update to my app to the app store but I get this error.

"To configure this app as an iOS routing app, the app's Info.plist must contain the MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes key."

I have never gotten this before nor do I need it to be a routing app so does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try this [link][1] you got the solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259030/ios-app-submission-routing-app

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode's "Find in Workspace" for the keyword "MKDirectionsRequest".  Xcode seems to love inserting this in difficult to find places.  Remove that from your Info.plist and resubmit.