# I keep getting ITMS-90116 error from App Store Connect

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, app-store, mapkit

ITMS-90116: Invalid Info.plist: To include the MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes key in the Info.plist, you must define the app binary as a routing app.

This is the email from App Store but I reupload the project removing that property from plist and I still get this error. My app does use MapKit but it doesn't provide routing in the Apple's mapview. I just redirect the user to Apple Maps with coordinates with this code:

```
func openMapsAppWithDirections(to coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, destinationName name: String) {
    let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = name 
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
}
```

What do you think I should focus on to solve this error?

Comment: This could help! [IOS App Submission Routing App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259030/ios-app-submission-routing-app)

Comment: I tried that but doesn't help

Comment: Have you tried setting the options nil instead of saying that you are using it for driving.

Comment: I set the options nil and didn't get the error. For now, it seems like it is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the options to `nil`

```
mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: nil)
```

You are telling the app/Apple that you are using this for driving with

```
let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
```